# unable to install webapps from firefox in 14.10

Tags: firefox, 14.10, webapps

I've upgraded to 14.10 and I'm not able to install webapps from Firefox. For example, when I'm on Twitter I've the popup asking me if I want to install it but if I select "install" it does nothing.

I'm wondering if the versions of the Firefox's addons aern't guilty, since I use the service "Sync" of Firefox to sync all my browsers. See below the Ubuntu related plugins:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Normally clicking install in Firefox should install the unity-webapps-twitter package, please verify that it is installed (e.g. run apt-cache policy unity-webapps-twitter on a terminal).
After the package is installed you should open the dash an type twitter to open the webapp, then you can pin in to the starter by right clicking the twitter icon.